# I need to display a pdf in my google drive as a thumbnail ,in a google sheet..how to do it Using google script?

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, thumbnails

I have a folder in google drive which contains pdfs. Some of them contain images and some do not. I need to display each of those pdf files as thumbnails in a google sheet using a google script. Please help me if you know any method to do it...

Comment: After testing, I don't think this is doable, I wrote the code below which works well with pictures and videos, but it does not work with PDFs, I believe it may be related with the size of the thumbnail or perhaps the way they are stored in non videos/picture files.

Answer (score 1):

You can create Thumbnail of pdf file and save it to drive.
If you want resize thumb, you can use thumbnailLink.

1. Read file pdf to get thumbnail:
   `var file = DriveApp.getFileById('xxxx- file id');`
2. Get thumbnail blob:
   `var thumbBlob = file.getThumbnail();`
3. Save thumbnail to Drive:
   `var res = Drive.Files.insert({title: "temp.jpg"}, thumbBlob);`
4. Get thumbnailLink:
   `Logger.log(file.thumbnailLink);`

The thumbnailLink is *https:// lh3.googleusercontent.com/.....=s220*. You have to change 220 to your desired width.